# Throw Away Dial-Up Account

Tags: internet, remote, networking, slow-connection

I'm going away on vacation to a location in Canada where highspeed internet access is not readily available. There's been a dial up connection until this year, where it got cancelled to save money as it wasn't being used 9 months of the year. I'd like to have an internet connection in case some catastrophic happens, as well as to check my e-mail. My thought was to just purchase a dial-up account for a month to do so. Is there any service that provides a connection for a single month, rather than trying to get you to sign up for a yearly plan, or lock you in to a yearly deal? Is there a better solution to this problem that can be done at *reasonable* rates?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you're headed WAY out in the sticks for you to say "in Canada where highspeed internet access is not readily available."  We're having fiber-to-the-home laid in my part of this city in the not-too-distant future.

Comment: Will there be cellphone reception?  If so, you got some options...

Comment: I'm way out in the sticks, with no cell phone reception. I'm originally from Canada, so I have no crazy perception of Canada where I think Toronto doesn't have electricity or anything =) We just happen to be going to a cottage across a lake where the closest town has <1000 people and the closest hospital is ~45 min. away.

Answer (score 2):

Since I live in Australia its hard to suggest solutions for you to use.

However if I was in your position I would try:

- Mobile Broadband: You can buy pre paid data sticks that connect via wireless
- An existing dialup account usually comes with your current ISP
- Your vacation spot may have a available internet connection for you to use.
- Internet over a phone/Smart phone (may be more costly)

Answer (score 1):

If you have DSL access at home, you could try to see if your provider offers a free dialup account with it. I believe AT&T (formerly SBC) does this.

Comment: I don't actually have DSL at home, I have cable. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your current ISP supports iPass. If they do, [use this page](http://www.ipass.com/ipass_apfinder.html) to find a local POP and dial-in to there. We don't have this any more but we used to a few years ago and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Telus is probably the best choice for dial-up in Canada:

[Dial-up Internet Service](http://business.telus.com/en_CA/National/products/Small_Business/Internet_And_Data/Internet_Access/details/natSmbDialUpInternet.html#tab1)

It's been a while since I had an account with them and I can't find anything on their site about whether you could sign up for just one month or not.  They have local numbers in most Canadian cities, even out in the boonies.